# Why are query results across linked servers of different versions completely wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 running a stored procedure which hits other servers running 2008.

A very straightforward query is returning utterly incorrect results.

```
SELECT 
   c.acctno, c.provcode, p.provcode, p.provname, c.poscode AS ChargePOS, 
   pos.poscode, pos.posdesc
FROM
   Server2008.charge_t as c
inner join 
   Server2008.provcode_t as p on c.provcode = p.provcode
inner join 
   Server2008.poscode_t as pos on c.poscode = pos.poscode
inner join 
   Server2008.patdemo_t as pat on c.acctno = pat.acctno
left join 
   Server2008.billareacode_t as b on c.billingarea = b.billareacode
Where 
   c.proccode in ('G0438', 'G0439', '99420')
   and c.correction = 'N' 
   and (c.priinscode in ('0001', '001A', '001B')
         or c.secinscode in ('0001', '001A', '001B'))
   and year(c.dateofservice) = year(getdate())
```

Note the `INNER JOIN` from `poscode_t` to `charge_t` table (second inner join) where `c.poscode = pos.poscode`. This is very simple, standard stuff here.

When this is executed on the 2005 server, the results are just wrong. I get the following:

```
acctno  | patlname      |  patfname     | ChargeProv    |   ProvProv    |   provname        |   ChargePOS   |   poscode     |   posdesc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | person1       |  Person1      | 28            |   28          | Doctor28          |   07          |   323         |  Site323
2       | person2       |  person2      | 24            |   24          | Doctor24          |   07          |   323         |  Site323
```

In both example, the ChargePOS (07) and the poscode (323) are clearly not the same, which the join should ensure they were.

When I run this query on Server2008 itself, the results are correct. When I run it on a 2012 server, the results are correct. It's only when I run it on the 2005 server. It makes no difference what version of SSMS I use.

I've broken the query down to run piece by piece adding in the joins one at a time. If I specify an acctno in the WHERE, the results are correct.

Has anyone seen anything like this? It's like the link itself is bad or there's some sort of junk in a hung transaction out there that's messing with things only on this server. Any ideas where to look are helpful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What datatype is the column?

Comment: Why would they be the same?  I don't even see `ChargePOS` anywhere in your query.  Are you sure you are posting the query that generated these results?

Comment: Yeah I was going to say the same thing after another look, I can't see ChargePOS anywhere..

Comment: You are correct, but the issue was only in what I posted here when changing it so it could be posted publicly. The original script is fine and works on all servers except the one 2005 server. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to the overall issue, but I've discovered a couple of things that affect the results.

1. Changing the joins to LEFT corrects the problem when running it on the 2005 server.
2. Adding the hint  OPTION ( MERGE JOIN ) corrects it as well.

None of this explains why it runs properly on all other servers but horribly wrong on this one server. Changing the joins to LEFT didn't alter the execution plan's structure but adding the hint did.

We're to a point where we need to bring in an expert because working around the problem isn't acceptable in this case. I still welcome any ideas for what might be happening here.